# Only element in xslt result set is not the last element?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the following snippet

```
<xsl:for-each select="book">
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/><xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want it to be a list of comma-separated book titles.

The output is correct when I have no books in the list. It is also correct when I have more than one book.

However, if I have exactly one book, it prints a comma at the end.
When I change the condition to only print a comma if it is the last element, the case where there is only one book doesn't print a comma.

So it seems like when there is only one element it is not treated as the last element. How can I deal with this?

Sample XML: looks something like this

```
<booklist>
  <book>
    <title>My book</title>
    <author>Some author</author>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>Another book</title>
    <author>Another author</author>
  </book>
</booklist>
```

When there are two books in the list, I get

`My book, Another book`

When I delete the second entry, I get

`My book,`

EDIT:

I found the issue. I was using an `<xsl:apply-templates>` to select a set of data, and then inside another template for each book, I was doing the position check. However, `last()` was referring to the original set of data and not the filtered subset.

Comment: Can you share the XML you are using? Your transformation looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me in Firefox (I get no commas for no books, and *n*-1 commas for *n* books if *n*>0). I suspect your XSLT processor is broken.

The XSLT ("x.xsl"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" media-type="text/xhtml" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/book">
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/><xsl:if test="position() != last()">;</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="x.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
  <book>
    <title>A</title>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>B</title>
  </book>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's "test()"? I think you want "last()-1".

Comment: Sorry typo I meant `last()` Actually, why do I want `last() - 1`? Is it zero-indexed? I have tried the suggestion but the comma is still there for the case of one book.